# MvcSiteMapProvider not working with simple MVC.SiteMap file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

So this is a little strange. I have a VERY simple sitemap (reduced to this simplicity for debugging -- live version is much more complex):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" enableLocalization="false">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Why Buy Your New Home" Controller="WhyBuyYourNewHome" Action="Index" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

When I try to load the page, I get the following error:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Source Error:

Line 75:             else
Line 76:             {
Line 77:                 returnValue = UrlHelper.Action(action, controller, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues));
Line 78:             }
Line 79: 


Source File: C:\sitemap\Branches\3.0.0\MvcSiteMapProvider\MvcSiteMapProvider\DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver.cs    Line: 77
```

The strange this is that if I remove the "Why Buy Your New Home" node, it works. Also, the following works just fine and loads all of my dynamic nodes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" enableLocalization="true">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Find Your New Home" controller="FindYourNewHome" action="Index">
          <mvcSiteMapNode title="Markets" action="Market" updatePriority="Critical" dynamicNodeProvider="MyProject.MVC.Extensions.SiteMap.SiteMapMarketNodeProvider, MyProject.MVC.Extensions">
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="Communities" action="Community" updatePriority="High" dynamicNodeProvider="MyProject.MVC.Extensions.SiteMap.SiteMapCommunityNodeProvider, MyProject.MVC.Extensions">
              <mvcSiteMapNode title="Driving Directions" action="DrivingDirections" updatePriority="High" dynamicNodeProvider="MyProject.MVC.Extensions.SiteMap.SiteMapDrivingDirectionsNodeProvider, MyProject.MVC.Extensions" />
              <mvcSiteMapNode title="Floorplans" action="Floorplan" updatePriority="High" dynamicNodeProvider="MyProject.MVC.Extensions.SiteMap.SiteMapFloorplanNodeProvider, MyProject.MVC.Extensions" />          
            </mvcSiteMapNode>
          </mvcSiteMapNode>
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

It only seems to be when I add in very simplistic nodes that I'm getting this duplicate key error, yet if you look at my first XML sample, there's no duplicate key possible. If I add that "Why Buy Your New Home" node to my the last XML sample that includes the dynamic node providers, it breaks again. Any help on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it ended up being the fact that I had capitalized "Controller" and "Action" attributes in the XML. That was causing all nodes to fall to my "catchall" route so technically all of my site map nodes matched a single route.

Grrr....

Answer (score 1):

This most likely means the URL is the same for that WhyBuy node and some other url.  Maybe you could post your routing?

Comment: I thought of that as well and checked my routes but they're all unique. This happens no matter what extra node I put where the "Why Buy Your New Home" node is. I just picked on that one for demo purposes.

Comment: @Scott Schluer - Hrm, pretty sure its something like that.  I've ran into this before and that was the issue.  There is another dupe key issue where internally MvcSitemap keys things with a a controller_action_title index or something.  Maybe thats the issue?  I'm still pretty confidant its the url and your routes are the problem.

Comment: I'll run through everything one more time, maybe a little more carefully and see if I can't find something. The strange thing is that it's doing this with only a "Home" and one secondary node no matter what that node is. Thx for the help, I'll reply when I've had a chance to check it out a little more.

Comment: Ok, so I stripped my routes down to just the two referenced in the sitemap and left the sitemap stripped down to those two nodes. Still getting the same error. :-<